# Azure Monitor / Log Analytics metric alert query

Tags: azure, logging, monitor

I have an Azure Monitor log analytics workspace. I have the MMA agent installed on an Exchange server on-premises and it's uploading event and perf data to Azure. I can chart the monitor I'm interested in, based on this query:

```
Perf
| where CounterName == "Free Megabytes" and InstanceName == "D:" 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)
| where Computer == "EXCH13.xxx.local"
```

I need to create an alert when available disk space goes below 20 GB but in trying to create a log based alert it's just alerting based on the number of times the query has run in a given time. And when I try to create a metrics based alert is says the query must include 'AggregatedValue' and 'bin(TimeGenerated, [roundTo])'. I just need it to look at the log data and let me know when it goes below 20 GB. Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding the issue, have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log?

Comment: Hi Jim, yes I've had a look at that doc. I tried:
Perf
| where CounterName == "Free Megabytes" and InstanceName == "D:" 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)
| where Computer == "EXCH13.stepsemployment.local" 
| summarize AggregatedValue=sum(Count) by bin (timestamp,5min)

And
| summarize AggregatedValue=sum(Free Megabytes) by bin (timestamp,5min) 

I just don't know how to format it so that a metric alert works. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? It may help more people who have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, we can use the following query to view the log when the free disk space goes below xxx GB.
For example

```
Perf
| where CounterName == "Free Megabytes" and InstanceName == "D:"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)
| where Computer == "jimtest"
| where CounterValue <= 30720 (free disk space goes below 30 GB)
```

It will return logs with less than 30gb of free disk space.
[image]

Regarding how to create alert condition, please refer to the following picture
[image]
It means that we will receive the alert when the number of logs with less than 20gb of free disk space.

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-unified-log).
[image]

---

## Update

According to my research, Azure monitor also provides the template of metrics `Logical Disk Free Megabytes`. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-performance-counters). 
1. Configure workspace to collect the metric
[image]
[image]

2. configure condition 
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Hi Jim, that worked a treat - thanks so much for you help.

Comment: @Paulschnack Since it is useful for you, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It can help more people who have similar problem.